# Multiple HTML Elements on jQuery UI Tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQueryUI Tabs and have a requirement to add UI elements to each tab that allow a user to Edit information about the tab, or remove the tab.

The markup I use on the `<li>` for a given tab looks like this:

```
<li>
    <div style="background-color:Red;"> <-- Red to see what's happening -->
        <a href="#tabs-1"><span>Tab One</span></a>
        <div style="text-align:right; margin-right:3px;">
            <div><span id="editTab-1">edit</span></div>
            <div><span id="delTab-1">X</span></div>
        </div>            
    </div>
</li>
```

This renders just as I would hope in IE

```
 ______________________________
|                          Edit|
|      Tab One                 |
|___________________________X__|
```

but it does not render properly in Chrome or FireFox (the tab is only wide enough for the "Tab One" text, and "Edit" / "X" are mostly "under" the tab (lower Z-Index apparently).

What is a compatible way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Could you make a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) demonstrating you issue?

Comment: @Scott: Here's a working jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/WYXAB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you were intending or not, as I haven't tested in IE, but this works in Chrome and FF:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul style="cursor:pointer">    
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-1">
                <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">Tab One</div>
                <div style="float: right; text-align:right;">
                    <div id="editTab-1">edit</div>
                    <div id="delTab-1">X</div>
                </div>  
            </a>
        </li>   
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-2">
                <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">Tab Two</div>
                <div style="float: right; text-align:right;">
                    <div id="editTab-2">edit</div>
                    <div id="delTab-2">X</div>
                </div>  
            </a>
        </li>   
    </ul>        

    <div id="tabs-1" class="tabPane">Tab One Content</div>  
    <div id="tabs-2" class="tabPane">Tab Two Content</div>    
</div>
```

***[See the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYXAB/1/)***

---

If you want to handle the clicks dynamically, you could use:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

$tabs.find("a div[id]").on("click", function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id"),
        idTab = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1)),            
        isEdit = id.indexOf("edit") > -1,
        isDelete = id.indexOf("del") > -1,        
        index = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');

    if (index + 1 === idTab) {
        if (isEdit) { 
            console.log("Edit Tab " + (index+1)); 
            //however you want to edit here
        }

        if (isDelete) { 
            console.log("Delete Tab " + (index+1)); 
            $tabs.tabs("remove", index);
        }
    }

}).css("cursor", "pointer");​
```

***[See the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYXAB/3/)***

Comment: Works in IE too, though there's a minor display issue with the tab being higher than it otherwise was.  I'm looking into that now.  Might be due to other CSS on my page.

Comment: I'm in the middle of working out the clicking particulars of the Edit and X inside of the selected Tab. I'm trying to bind click events via `$("#tabs").tabs({ create : function(event, ui) { ...  }) });`

Comment: @Scott: I have the clicking working... just use `$('#editTab-1').click(...)`

Comment: @EricJ. - I have a slightly more dynamic approach if you check my edit.

Comment: @EricJ. - I went ahead and updated it a slight bit more adding in the call to actually remove the tab when the X is clicked, as well as styling Edit and X to have `cursor: pointer` by chaining that on the end there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, I think, stems from the fact that the tab `<li>` and then the `<a>` inside are floating elements, as designed in the jQueryUI CSS.

The technical part can best be summed up with this quote (from http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm)

> If no width is set, the results can be unpredictable. Theoretically, a floated element with an undefined width should shrink to the widest element within it. This could be a word, a sentence or even a single character - and results can vary from browser to browser.

So the red `<div>` is shrinking to the widest element - the `<a>`. IE and Firefox/Chrome are simply behaving differently, just their interpretation of the specifications. To be honest, that fact that Firefox and Chrome are similar and IE has had a [long history of float bugs](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html) I'd side with Mozilla/Google here although can appreciate that IE seems to be behaving nicer in this instance.

You can solve the problem by simply setting a width on the red `<div>`. However the markup could also be a bit cleaner, for example:

```
<li style="background-color:red;width:150px">
    <a href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a>
    <div id="editTab-1" style="text-align:right;margin-right:3px">edit
        <p id="delTab-1">X</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

gives the same result.

Comment: Setting a fixed-width certainly solves the issue.  Are you aware of a solution that does not require pre-selecting a width?

Comment: Much like Scott's answer you could add a `float:right` to the `<div id="editTab-x"/>` and remove the width to get the same result.